# Flickr for Windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, flickr

So I am not sure why this isn't working. It was working fine until I started to make the SearchResults. When I run the application I get no errors but I am told it runs but wont load the results as image tiles.

Here is the FlickrImage.cs file

```
namespace LookAroundMe
{


     public class FlickrImage
        {

            public Uri Image320 { get; set; }
            public Uri Image1024 { get; set; }

            public async static Task<List<FlickrImage>> GetFlickrImages(
                string flickrApiKey,
                double latitude = double.NaN,
                double longitude = double.NaN)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var baseUrl = getBaseUrl(flickrApiKey, latitude, longitude);

                string flickrResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);


                FlickrData apidata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlickrData>(flickrResult);

                List<FlickrImage> images = new List<FlickrImage>();


                if (apidata.stat == "ok")
                {
                    foreach (Photo data in apidata.photos.photo)
                    {
                        FlickrImage img = new FlickrImage();
                        //to retrive one photo, use this format:
                        //http://farm{farmid}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_{size}.jpg

                        string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}";

                        string baseFlickrUrl = string.Format(photoUrl,
                            data.farm,
                            data.server,
                            data.id,
                            data.secret);

                        img.Image320 = new Uri(baseFlickrUrl + "_n.jpg");
                        img.Image1024 = new Uri(baseFlickrUrl + "_b.jpg");

                        images.Add(img);
                    }
                }

                return images;
            }

                    private static string getBaseUrl(
                        string flickrApiKey, 
                        double latitude = double.NaN, 
                        double longitude = double.NaN)
                    {
                         //Licenses https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html
                /*  <license id="4" name="Attribution License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" />
                    <license id="5" name="Attribution-ShareAlike License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" />
                    <license id="6" name="Attribution-NoDerivs License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/" />
                    <license id="7" name="No known copyright restrictions" url="http://flickr.com/commons/usage/" />
                 */

                string license = "4,5,6,7";
                license = license.Replace(",", "%2C");

                if (!double.IsNaN(latitude))
                    latitude = Math.Round(latitude, 5);

                if (!double.IsNaN(longitude))
                    longitude = Math.Round(longitude, 5);

                string url = " https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/" +
                        "?method=flickr.photos.search" +
                        "&license={0}" +
                        "&api_key={1}" +
                        "&lat={2}" +
                        "&lon={3}" +
                        "&radius=2" +
                        "&format=json" +
                        "&nojsoncallback=1";

                var baseUrl = string.Format(url,
                    license,
                    flickrApiKey,
                    latitude,
                    longitude);


                             return baseUrl;
                    }

                }


            }
```

Here is the SearchResults.xaml.cs

I am not sure where its going wrong but have a feeling its with the FlickrImage.cs

```
   namespace LookAroundMe
    {
        public partial class SearchResults : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            private double _latitude;
            private double _longitude;

            private const string FlickrApiKey = "d88d5058647af8b07c74004becde025c";


            public SearchResults()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Loaded += SearchResults_Loaded;
            }

            void SearchResults_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               // LocationTextBlock.Text = string.Format("Location: {0} & {1}", _latitude, _longitude);

                var images = FlickrImage.GetFlickrImages(FlickrApiKey,
                    _latitude,
                    _longitude);

                DataContext = images;

            }

            protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

                _latitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["latitude"]);
                _longitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["longitude"]);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what about it isn't working?  do you have binding errors? do you see calls going out over the network?  time to start using a debugger and stepping through your code.

Comment: The app isn't showing up photos from Flickr when I try to search for photos from there around a gps location where the phone is at (or in this case, where I have set it). I am not getting any errors at all when running the app and my beginning knowledge doesn't help with debugging since I am not sure whats wrong. There are no red lines when I run the application.

Comment: first, i'd put a breakpoint in `SearchResults_Loaded`, and see (1) is it getting executed, and (2), is it returning any results.  maybe the query returned 0 images?  if it returned 0, put a breakpoint in `GetFlickrImages` and step through and make sure the web request succeeded, etc.  also, since this is a phone app, did you properly set the capabilities up to allow outgoing network access?

Comment: So I am getting images Count = 0 when I put a break into the FlickrImage.cs. So it has to do with something I did with Flickr?

Comment: perhaps?  maybe your api key is invalid.  maybe there aren't any images available in the geographical area you selected, etc.  try doing those same http requests from a browser and see what you get as responses?

Comment: I got a new api key from Flickr and that didn't change anything. When I bring up those http requests in a browser I get a website that explains each license break down and what they mean. An actual website shows up.

Comment: OMG YES I got it to work. I went back to your second post and dug a little deeper into the coding. I forgot to add protected async to the SearchResults_Loaded in the SearchResults.xaml.cs. Thanks for all your help. Greatly appreicated. so the var images = await FlickrImage.GetFlickrImages wasnt working. Finally!

Comment: you should add that as an answer, and then accept that answer, so people know what you fixed and don't find your open question with no answer :)

Comment: Even more noob, new to stack overflow. How do I do that? I dont see a button that says anything like that or that the question has been answered.

Comment: down below this, there's a big box with "Your Answer" and a textbox.  add your answer about what you had wrong and how you fixed it, and click "Post your answer".  After you've done that, there should be a checkbox icon you can click to mark as the correct answer (since you answered it, you might have to wait before that appears?)

Answer (score 0):

first, i'd put a breakpoint in SearchResults_Loaded, and see (1) is it getting executed, and (2), is it returning any results. maybe the query returned 0 images? if it returned 0, put a breakpoint in GetFlickrImages and step through and make sure the web request succeeded, etc. also, since this is a phone app, did you properly set the capabilities up to allow outgoing network access? –  John Gardner Mar 6 at 23:06